# My friend can't connect to my world on Minecraft: Pocket Edition, but I can connect to hers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend and I want to connect to the same Minecraft: Pocket Edition world. She wants to connect to one of my worlds, however every time we try get on the same world my game won't show up on her screen.

She can't get on my world I can get on one of hers.

We're both on the same Wi-Fi. I've tried searching for fixes to this problem however I can't find it useful answer.

I have an Android device and she has an Apple device.

Comment: Is she showing up in your world?

Comment: Yes but she can't get on my world I can get on hers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going into your settings and enabling "Local Server Multiplayer" on your device?

[image: Enable it here.]